# Getting sheet to not update all at once

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm making a sheet that imports a large amount of data from a site. I want to do this slowly so as not to clog up the site.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3]; 

  for (var i=1; i<39 ; i++){
    var cell = sheet.getRange(1, (i*2)-1);
    cell.setValue(=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("WEBSITE","table",table_number), "QUERY STUFF",0));
    Utilities.sleep(10000)
  }
}
```

All this does it make it dump everything once the loop is done executing.
So all IMPORTHTMLs go off at once. The opposite of what I'd like.

I'd like the sheet to update the cell value as it loops, and wait for the data to import (maybe 10 seconds) before going to the next iteration. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`SpreadsheetApp.flush();` mid-loop accomplishes my goals.

Comment: While setValue is working for you, it worth to note that there is a specfic method to add a formula:  `setFormula`

Comment: @Rubén Move this comment to below the question?

Comment: @JanDoggen Here is fine